# create ITypeInfo Object without tlb file

Tags: visual-c++, com, idispatch, typelib

I want to create a ITypeInfo Object Without tlb file.

```
class CExternalHelperM:public IDispatch,public IDocHostUIHandler
{
public:
CExternalHelperM();
virtual ~CExternalHelperM();

BEGIN_JSOBJECT_MAP()
    JSOBJECT_MAP(L"config",CConfigObject)
    JSOBJECT_MAP(L"sqlite",CSqliteObject)
    JSOBJECT_MAP(L"filesystem",CFileSystemObject)
END_JSOBJECT_MAP()

int SetExternal(IUnknown* pUnknow);

STDMETHOD(ShowContextMenu)( DWORD dwID, POINT *ppt, IUnknown *pcmdtReserved, IDispatch *pdispReserved );
STDMETHOD(GetHostInfo)( DOCHOSTUIINFO *pInfo );
STDMETHOD(ShowUI)( DWORD dwID, IOleInPlaceActiveObject *pActiveObject, IOleCommandTarget *pCommandTarget, IOleInPlaceFrame *pFrame, IOleInPlaceUIWindow *pDoc );
STDMETHOD(HideUI)( void );
STDMETHOD(UpdateUI)( void );
STDMETHOD(EnableModeless)( BOOL fEnable );
STDMETHOD(OnDocWindowActivate)( BOOL fActivate );
STDMETHOD(OnFrameWindowActivate)( BOOL fActivate );
STDMETHOD(ResizeBorder)( LPCRECT prcBorder, IOleInPlaceUIWindow *pUIWindow, BOOL fRameWindow );
STDMETHOD(TranslateAccelerator)( LPMSG lpMsg, const GUID *pguidCmdGroup, DWORD nCmdID );
STDMETHOD(GetOptionKeyPath)( LPOLESTR *pchKey, DWORD dw );
STDMETHOD(GetDropTarget)( IDropTarget *pDropTarget, IDropTarget **ppDropTarget );
STDMETHOD(GetExternal)( IDispatch **ppDispatch );
STDMETHOD(TranslateUrl)( DWORD dwTranslate, OLECHAR *pchURLIn, OLECHAR **ppchURLOut );
STDMETHOD(FilterDataObject)( IDataObject *pDO, IDataObject **ppDORet );
STDMETHOD(QueryInterface)( REFIID riid, void **ppvObject );

STDMETHOD(GetTypeInfoCount)( UINT *pctinfo);
STDMETHOD(GetTypeInfo)( UINT iTInfo, LCID lcid, ITypeInfo **ppTInfo );
STDMETHOD(GetIDsOfNames)( REFIID riid, LPOLESTR *rgszNames, UINT cNames, LCID lcid, DISPID *rgDispId );
STDMETHOD(Invoke)( DISPID dispIdMember, REFIID riid, LCID lcid, WORD wFlags, DISPPARAMS *pDispParams, VARIANT *pVarResult, EXCEPINFO *pExcepInfo, UINT *puArgErr );

virtual ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddRef( void );
virtual ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE Release( void );
private:
LONG                m_cRef;
BOOL                m_bEnableMenu;
};
```

i want to implement method GetTypeInfo,so i need to return a pointer of ITypeInfo,but i don't have tlb file.
after google it,i found this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221237%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

i need more information about how to create ITypeInfo Object without tlb file.
"METHOD0","METHOD1" is not defined.

Comment: If you return 0 to GetTypeInfoCount (`*pctinfo=0`), you can avoid implementing GetTypeInfo

Comment: in javascript need to enumerate all of the method and property,so the typeinfo is necessary!

Comment: METHOD0, METHOD1 are just macros you can declare to help define METHODDATA structure quicker. Something like `#define METHOD0(szName, iMeth, dispid, vtReturn) {NULL, NULL, dispid, iMeth, CALLCONV::CC_CDECL, 0, DISPATCH_METHOD, vtReturn}`

Comment: Maybe you should step back and explain what it is for. If you want to handle JS method/property requests on C++ side then it would make more sense to just support `IDispatchEx` on your interface instead of building dynamic type information.

Comment: thanks ,i will try to implements this interface .

Comment: in C++ how to control thr return value of the javascript function typeof ?

Comment: @RomanR.  in C++ how to control thr return value of the javascript function typeof ?